# Getting Data Out of Adwords Test Account

Tags: c#, api, google-ads-api

My Adwords Production Account Developer Token is in Pending stage, I have created a Test Account with a separate email address as per directions, Is there any way I can link the test account with Production MCC and pull data out of it i`m using Adwords C# client.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/

They provided a developer area, use the API and read the documentation. Not much else we can say?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was struggling to find out how to get some valid test data from an Adwords test account, and thought I'd post my solution here.

The official documentation

(found here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#developing_with_test_accounts)

suggests injecting the values like below and reading them from a variable instead of an API request

```
"CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT (Mar 20, 2013-Mar 23, 2013)"
Day,Campaign,Campaign ID,Impressions,Clicks,Cost
20130320,Widgets,123,1211,19,14.92
20130320,Sprockets,456,300,4,2.92
20130321,Widgets,123,901,12,9.86
20130321,Sprockets,456,340,5,3.86
20130322,Widgets,123,1065,16,11.23
20130322,Sprockets,456,509,6,5.23
20130323,Widgets,123,1005,15,10.12
20130323,Sprockets,456,287,3,1.12
```

Cheers